# CSV Column Insertion via awk

Tags: csv, unix, awk

I am trying to insert a column in front of the first column in a comma separated value file (CSV). At first blush, `awk` seems to be the way to go but, I'm struggling with how to move down the new column.

**CSV File**

```
A,B,C,D,E,F
1,2,3,4,5,6
2,3,4,5,6,7
3,4,5,6,7,8
4,5,6,7,8,9
```

**Attempted Code**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$1=$1 OFS (FNR<1 ? $1 "0\nA\n2\nC" : "col")}1'
```

**Result**

```
A,col,B,C,D,E,F
1,col,2,3,4,5,6
2,col,3,4,5,6,7
3,col,4,5,6,7,8
4,col,5,6,7,8,9
```

**Expected Result**

```
col,A,B,C,D,E,F
0,1,2,3,4,5,6
A,2,3,4,5,6,7
2,3,4,5,6,7,8
C,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please do let us know how values are getting added in new first column? thank you(NOT my downvote btw).

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily done using `paste + printf`:

```bash
paste -d, <(printf "col\n0\nA\n2\nC\n") file

col,A,B,C,D,E,F
0,1,2,3,4,5,6
A,2,3,4,5,6,7
2,3,4,5,6,7,8
C,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

`<(...)` is process substitution available in `bash`. For other shells use a pipeline like this:

```bash
printf "col\n0\nA\n2\nC\n" | paste -d, - file
```

Comment: Thank you very much @anubhava! Very clever use of bash process substitution, coupled with `paste`! I will accept your answer.

Comment: Whenever we need vertical join of dataset `paste` is the right tool for that.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` only you could try following solution, written and tested with shown samples.

```bash
awk -v value="$(echo -e "col\n0\nA\n2\nC")" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  num=split(value,arr,ORS)
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    newVal[i]=arr[i]
  }
}
{
  $1=arr[FNR] OFS $1
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

- First of all creating `awk` variable named `value` whose value is `echo`(shell command)'s output. NOTE: using `-e` option with `echo` will make sure that `\n` aren't getting treated as literal characters.
- Then in `BEGIN` section of `awk` program, setting `FS` and `OFS` as `,` here for all line of Input_file.
- Using `split` function on value variable into array named arr with delimiter of `ORS`(new line).
- Then traversing through for loop till value of num(total values posted by `echo` command).
- Then creating array named `newVal` with index of i(1,2,3 and so on) and its value is array arr value.
- In main `awk` program, setting first field's value to array arr value and $1 and printing the line then.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing your answer @RavinderSingh13! The effort is much appreciated.

Comment: @arnpry, Your welcome, I have added detailed explanation of my answer also in my answer.